# How to give javascript alert from web context(Iframe) in metro app.

Tags: iframe, windows-8, alert

In my metro app ..I am using iframe to load a web application - basically a form which contains some controls and finally user click on finish button and i want to show alert

i know in metro app. we can give the alert using "new Windows.UI.PopupMessage" to show the alert. but how can i do the same from the web context(Iframe).

i have a function (showalert();) in my default.js where i am using the "new Windows.UI.PopupMessage" to show messages. if i am trying to access this function from iframe page like "window.parent.showalert();". i get exception saying access denied.

Please someone reply to this as this is very critical for me.

thanks & regards
Goutham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML 5's [postMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015(v=vs.85).aspx) to communicate between contexts.

Below is an image of a simplistic example with the relevant code snippets following it; the [Bing Maps trip optimizer example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Maps-trip-optimizer-c4e037f7) uses this same technique on a grander scale.

[image]

The main page (default.js), which is running in the local context, includes an IFRAME loaded in web context via the following markup (I left out the unchanged <head> element to save space):

```
<body onload="localContext.onLoad();">
   <p style="margin-top: 150px">This is default.html in the local context</p>

   <div style="background-color: azure; width: 300px">
       <iframe src="ms-appx-web:///webpage.html" />
   </div>
</body>
```

`localContext` is defined in default.js as

```
var localContext = {

    onLoad: function () {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage",
            function (msg) {
                if (msg.origin == "ms-appx-web://bfddc371-2040-4560-a61a-ec479ed996b0")
                    new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg.origin).showAsync().then();
            });
    }
```

};

and it defines an `onLoad` function for default.html that registers a listener to the `onmessage` event, and when that event fires a [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) is shown (or you can take whatever action you want to do in the local context).

Note that the parameter to the `message` event callback (`msg` here) also includes a origin property that you can check to make sure you're only handling messages from expected senders.

The web page hosted in the IFRAME calls [postMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015(v=vs.85).aspx) in the `onclick` event handler of a button (you'll probably want to pull the invocation a separate .js file versus in-line)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is webpage.html loaded into an iFrame
        <button id="button" onclick="window.parent.postMessage('Hello from Web Context', '*');">Say Hello</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, I don't know your app as well as you, but if you're using a MessageDialog to confirm successful submission of a form, you may want to rethink the user experience.  A MessageDialog is pretty obtrusive and shouldn't be used for notifications that are a natural part of the application workflow. As an alternative, you could indicate some type of success message on the surface of the UI itself, and perhaps clear it after some time or the user's next interaction with the app.